# dotnet new angular - dist not being updated?

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio, angular, typescript

I installed SPA templates (including angular) via `dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*`, per [Scott Hanselman's guide](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnetNewAngularAndDotnetNewReact.aspx).

Next, I created a new angular project: `dotnet new angular -n MyProject`

I opened this project in Visual Studio 2017. I ran it with Ctrl+F5, and the web site runs. I get a console screen telling me to go to http://localhost:5000. I go there and a site shows up in the browser, with a "Hello, World!" at the top of the page. A bunch of "info" appears in the console. So far so good.

I then go to `ClientApp/app/components/home/home.component.html`. I make a minor text change: I change `<h1>Hello, world!</h1>` to `<h1>Hello, Matt!</h1>`. In the console, I see a message `Node will restart because file changed: ...home.component.html`. Great. Except when I go to the browser, the change doesn't appear. It still says "Hello, world!". I've tried clearing cache, opening other browsers, etc, no dice.

I see no errors in the console or the browser console. It seems like `wwwroot/dist/main-client.js` is just not getting updated.

What am I missing? Why isn't this change being picked up?

**UPDATE:**

I have things partially figured out. I'm not ready to post an answer yet, because I'm not 100% sure I'm doing it right.

What I noticed was that when I run `webpack` from the command line, the dist folder got updated. Looking at the `Configure` method in `Startup`, I noticed that there is an `app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(...)`. I debugged through and realized this wasn't being called because `env.IsDeveloper()` was returning false. I looked at launchSettings.json (which got created by Visual Studio, not the template). I added ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ([you can see the before & after in this gist](https://gist.github.com/mgroves/aaa41de0491d73323b66594cbd0ec788)). Once I did that, any changes I make in the angular files cause a rebuild and the dist folder to be updated.

SO... is this a problem with the template, a problem with VS2017, or a problem with my own dev environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of installing the SPA templates, I would use the CLI to:

1- Install yo generator with "npm install -g yo"

2- Install the aspnetcore generator with "npm install -g yo generator-aspnetcore-spa"

3- Generate a new angular app using: "yo aspnetcore-spa"

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this info, what is the preferred debug launch using these templates?

Comment: Should step 3 be "yo aspnetcore-spa"?

Comment: You are right Andez I had the wrong command so I edited my answer. Thanks